# Distinguish between trace and debug messages in a Tracelistener

Tags: c#, trace, tracelistener

I have a program that tests c# scripts for a different program. When a script is written Debug.Writeline or Trace.Writeline methods can be used and the text is written to a richtextbox, I would like the text for the different methods to have different colours, Debug is orange, Trace is blue.

Just before I run the script I have

```
System.Diagnostics.Trace.Listeners.Add(new TextboxTraceListener(outputTxt, "ScriptTraceListener", Color.DarkBlue));
System.Diagnostics.Debug.Listeners.Add(new TextboxTraceListener(outputTxt, "ScriptDebugListener", Color.DarkOrange));
```

just after the script runs is

```
System.Diagnostics.Trace.Listeners.Remove("ScriptTraceListener");
System.Diagnostics.Debug.Listeners.Remove("ScriptDebugListener");
```

The TextBoxTraceListener is

```
class TextboxTraceListener : TraceListener
{

    private DebugRichTextbox output;
    private Color textColor;

    public TextboxTraceListener(DebugRichTextbox output) :this(output, "RichTextboxTraceListener", Color.Black)
    {
    }

    public TextboxTraceListener(DebugRichTextbox output, string name, Color textColor)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.output = output;
        this.textColor = textColor;
    }


    public override void Write(string message)
    {
        Action write = delegate() { output.write(message, this.textColor); };
        if (output.InvokeRequired)
        {
            IAsyncResult result = output.BeginInvoke(write);
            output.EndInvoke(result);
        }
        else
        {
            write();
        }
    }

    public override void WriteLine(string message)
    {
        Action writeLine = delegate() { output.writeLine(message, this.textColor); };
        if (output.InvokeRequired)
        {
            IAsyncResult result = output.BeginInvoke(writeLine);
            output.EndInvoke(result);
        }
        else
        {
            writeLine();
        }

    }
}
```

It appears that the Debug.Writeline and Trace.Writeline messages are caught by both listeners and the messages are just duplicated in the richtextbox in blue and orange. Is there a way of telling if the message is from the Debug or trace in TextBoxTraceListener?

Thanks,
Eoghan

Comment: Trace and Debug are both the same except, Trace listeners can read in both Debug and Release Mode, but Debug listeners can't in Release mode. You can probably have a work around for you, provide custom classes(Debug and Trace) that writes the text using Trace only and you can differentiate the color in their classes.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this. Doesn't look great but appears to work. I just add one listener which is an instance of this class. If anyone has a nicer solution I would be interested in it.

```
class TextboxTraceListener : TraceListener
{
private DebugRichTextbox output;
private Color debugColor;
private Color traceColor;

public TextboxTraceListener(DebugRichTextbox output) :this(output, "RichTextboxTraceListener", Color.Black, Color.Black)
{
}

public TextboxTraceListener(DebugRichTextbox output, string name, Color debugColor, Color traceColor)
{
    this.Name = name;
    this.output = output;
    this.debugColor = debugColor;
    this.traceColor = traceColor;
}


public override void Write(string message)
{
    Color thisColor = Color.Black;
    StackTrace trace = new StackTrace();
    StackFrame[] stackFrames = trace.GetFrames();
    if (Array.Exists(stackFrames, element => element.GetMethod().DeclaringType.Name.ToUpper().Equals("TRACE")))
    {
        thisColor = traceColor;
    }
    if (Array.Exists(stackFrames, element => element.GetMethod().DeclaringType.Name.ToUpper().Equals("DEBUG")))
    {
        thisColor = debugColor;
    }

    Action write = delegate() { output.write(message, thisColor); };
    if (output.InvokeRequired)
    {
        IAsyncResult result = output.BeginInvoke(write);
        output.EndInvoke(result);
    }
    else
    {
        write();
    }
}

public override void WriteLine(string message)
{

    Color thisColor = Color.Black;
    StackTrace trace = new StackTrace();
    StackFrame[] stackFrames = trace.GetFrames();
    if (Array.Exists(stackFrames, element => element.GetMethod().DeclaringType.Name.ToUpper().Equals("TRACE")))
    {
        thisColor = traceColor;
    }
    if (Array.Exists(stackFrames, element => element.GetMethod().DeclaringType.Name.ToUpper().Equals("DEBUG")))
    {
        thisColor = debugColor;
    }

    Action writeLine = delegate() { output.writeLine(message, thisColor); };
    if (output.InvokeRequired)
    {
        IAsyncResult result = output.BeginInvoke(writeLine);
        output.EndInvoke(result);
    }
    else
    {
        writeLine();
    }

}
}
```

Comment: You don't have any control over the application that is writing to Trace & Debug?

Comment: I have control of the application but the application is a UI for writing C# scripts, kind of like a dumbed down IDE. It is the scripts that are writing to Trace & Debug, I just attach the listener before it kicks off and remove it after it finishes. The bit of code that I have control of between those 2 points is just compiling the scripts that were written in the UI and calling a method on that assembly.